# Smooth Shading Issue

Tags: modeling

I'm modelling a lightsaber and I am now at the final stages but am stuck as when I smooth shade everything, there are still some lines that look flat and I'm not sure why.

You can see 3 lines on the top and then there's 3 lines directly on the bottom that remain flat. If I disable auto smooth, it turns into a bit of a mess.

I've also tried separating these into their own mesh and autosmooting but then the shading looks off when comparing the rest of it.

There's no deformity in the mesh either so I'm really not sure.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You may just want to subdivide it.

Comment: Are all the normals pointing the right way?